# Refresh div contents after making changes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Below is my code which is working fine...

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
function im()
{
    var Name=document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var pointsize=document.getElementById("pointsize").value;
    var format=document.getElementById("format").value;
    var bckclr=document.getElementById("bckclr").value;
    var color=document.getElementById("color").value;
    var bcolor=document.getElementById("bcolor").value;
    var font=document.getElementById("font").value;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = 'Name='+Name+'&pointsize='+pointsize+
                  '&format='+format+'&bckclr='+bckclr+
                  '&color='+color+'&bcolor='+bcolor+
                  '&font='+font;

        alert(url);
        //-----Sending request to server for getting job name list by ajax-----
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url : "i.php?",
            data    : url,              
            cache   : false,
            success : function(html) {
                //document.getElementById('Div_PJobId').style.display="block";
                //alert('hi');
                alert(html);
                var pic='<img src="'+html+'">';
                $("#Div_Im").html(pic).show();
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

and php code...

```
echo('Name: <input type="text" id="Name" onchange="im()" value="your name"  name="Name" />');

echo('pointsize: <input type="text" id="pointsize" onchange="im()" value="50" name="pointsize" />');

echo('format: <input type="text" id="format" value=".gif" onchange="im()" name="format" />');

echo('BackGround Color: <input type="text" id="bckclr" value="red" onchange="im()" name="bckclr" />');

echo('FontColor: <input type="text" id="color" value="white" onchange="im()" name="color" />');

echo('Border Color: <input type="text" id="bcolor" value="blue" onchange="im()" name="bcolor" />');

echo('<a href="./lang/ims.php"><img src="'.$image.'" height="82" width="82" /></a>');

echo('Font: <input type="text" id="font" value="'.$image1.'" onchange="im()" name="font" />');

echo ('<div id="Div_Im">');
echo('replace me');
echo ('</div>');
```

As you can see, I am using AJAX to fetch data from server and displayed within  its working fine but I need to refresh div everytime I make changes .

How to refresh div when I make some changes... also I need to add a symbol or loading image, when the data is being from server.....How to do that?

Comment: [Take a look here for jQuery ajax events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events).  You could update the div on "ajaxComplete" or "ajaxSuccess" event and handle loading symbol on "ajaxStart" and "ajaxStop" events.

Comment: Make changes to what? To any of your data (Name, pointsize, etc)? Please provide more details mate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#theIMform input')
    .change(function(){
      // Automatically creates a Query String for all fields within the parent form
      formdata = $(this).closest('form').serialize();

      $.ajax({
        type : "POST" ,
        url : "i.php" ,
        data : formdata ,              
        cache : false ,
        error : function( jqXHR , textStatus , errorThrown ){
          // Something went wrong
        } ,
        success : function( data , textStatus , jqXHR ){
          $( "#div_im" )
            .hide()
            .html( '<img src="'+data+'">' )
            .show();

        }
      });
    });

});
</script>
```

### PHP

```
?>
<form id="theIMform" name="theIMform">
  Name: <input type="text" id="Name" value="your name"  name="Name" />
  pointsize: <input type="text" id="pointsize" value="50" name="pointsize" />
  format: <input type="text" id="format" value=".gif" name="format" />
  BackGround Color: <input type="text" id="bckclr" value="red" name="bckclr" />
  FontColor: <input type="text" id="color" value="white" name="color" />
  Border Color: <input type="text" id="bcolor" value="blue" name="bcolor" />
  <a href="./lang/ims.php"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" height="82" width="82" /></a>
  Font: <input type="text" id="font" value="<?php echo $image1; ?>" name="font" />
</form>
<div id="div_im">replace me</div>
<?php
```

Comment: Does the page produce valid HTML? Is there already a `<form>` tag wrapped around the form fields? Have you checked the AJAX call using Firebug or Developer Tools to see whether it is being triggered or throwing an error? Have you been able to submit to the `i.php` form handler directly? Did it work as expected?

Comment: nope  i did not check in firebug.. is there a way i can fix this without using <form tag>

Comment: your code works exactly like mine...it works only for  Name: <input type="text" id="Name" value="your name"  name="Name" /> if a user makes changes to any other field it doe not repl;ace the div content immedtly.. we have to manually refresh the page....:(

Comment: Do you have this code running on a publicly accessible server somewhere? If you can provide a URL, it would be useful.

Comment: hoooo its in my local machine. my server code 'i.php'..`$Name=$_POST["Name"];
$pointsize=$_POST["pointsize"];
$bckclr=$_POST["bckclr"];
$color=$_POST["color"];
$bcolor=$_POST["bcolor"];
$format=$_POST["format"];
//$filename = "./lang/sri".$format;
$filename = "./lang/".$Name.$format;
$font=$_POST["font"]; 

$cmd = " -background $bckclr -pointsize $pointsize -font $font -fill $color ".
" -strokewidth 1 -stroke $bcolor label:\"$Name\" ";

exec("convert $cmd $filename");
//if($filename)
//{}
//echo('<img src="'.$filename.'">');
echo $filename;`

Answer (score -1):

**When you change a page element it's refreshed automatically.**

I think your problem is about this line

```
$("#Div_Im").html(pic).show();
```

because you call show to the img element and not on the div.

try to change it in

```
$("#Div_Im").html(pic);
$("#Div_Im").show();
```

furthermore i suggest you use jquery to get values, so you need to change  `color=document.getElementById("color").value;` in a more easy `color = $('#color').val();`

Comment: hi KernelFolla, i have replaced the code with what you have mentioned... but still not working  it works only for `id="Name"`.....:(everytime i need to refresh page to get "div content.."

Comment: You are able to chain methods in jQuery, so `$('#Div_Im').html(pic).show()` === `$('#Div_Im').html(pic);$('#Div_Im').show()`.